# Apex Charts showing blank graph

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

`I'm using apex charts its getting data but its not showing the graph just showing blank graph, there are saveral other charts also they are working fine just this graph is not working.

`geting this error:`
`Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
`at apexcharts.common.js:6:6976`
`at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)`
`at Function.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:6864)`
`at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:189758)`
`at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:199786)`
`at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:198887)`
`at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14:37019)`
`at t.create (apexcharts.common.js:6:4477)`
`at apexcharts.common.js:14:36100`

I have tried updating the library also.

I have tried updating the library also.`